# Composer update undo deleted vendor

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

Does composer do any backups of an vendor repo folder before delete it/or update it? When yes where I can find the backup folder?

I did an composer update of the main bundle it deleted my vendor bundle where an unpushed branch was open, because the my vendor bundle was not in the composer.json. So I hope maybe I can get the changes from a backup which composer maybe create before delete a folder?

Comment: So you ignored the warnings about changes files in the `vendor` folder being overwritten when you ran `composer update`, and you were working on code directly in the `vendor` folder? Sorry, because of these safeguards, composer does NOT backup the vendor folder.

Comment: When you commit the change but not push it, composer will not warn you about, when you did change back to the composer branch. Normally its not a problem when you dont push it only when the vendor was deleted from composer.json. When there is no backup its time to to it again and better. Thx for the answer.

Comment: I see what you're saying - the branch was tracked in `.git` but not currently loaded? Either way there's two faults that led to the loss of your code.. 1) Working directly in the `vendor` folder 2) Not pushing your code right away - I always `git push` after any `git commit`. Can't do much about it now of course, but I'm pointing it out as steps to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Best practice in my opinion is: if you modify a vendor (and intend to push it later on), move it out of the vendor into your src. Then you can safely remove it from the json and do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No, Composer doesn't do that. Your changes are lost now.

To avoid such problems in the future, I would recommend to make the vendor directory something exclusively used by Composer. Try to never edit the vendor directory. Once you want to edit a vendor, there are 2 options:

- Move them to src
- Clone the original repo locally, work on it and require the local repository in your `composer.json`